# Polytope, Python - find extreme points

Tags: python, geometry, mathematical-optimization

I need to find a list of all the extreme points of a polytope given by a matrix relation Ax <= b, with x being non-negative. I know that 100% of the time, the polytope is non degenerate.
The first solution I used was to generate a random non negative vector and run an LP with the vector being the objective function (so basically; optimizing in a random direction). This of course has many problems: take an insane amount of time and in the end I can't be sure the solution is correct.

Then I tried using the [polytope](https://githubhot.com/repo/tulip-control/polytope) toolbox; with the 'extreme' function. I ran it on an instance I already know well:

```
import numpy as np
import polytope as pc
    
A = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0]])
K = A - A.transpose()
C = np.vstack( (K, -np.eye(5) , [1]*5)

p = pc.Polytope(C, [0]*10+[1])
print(pc.extreme(p))
```

The output I expect is (.5, .5, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0) and (0, 0, 0, 0, 0). However, I only get a None.
I saw there is an [example](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/main/examples/randplot.py) in the repository on the use of extreme() but I don't see what I did wrong.

On a side note, if you have an other library to recommand that can solve this problem (find extremal points in polyhedras) I'd be happy to take it.

Comment: I checked the definition of extreme() method and it seems like the issue comes from the fact my polytope is not of full dimension, but I still want to get the extreme points so I don't know what to do

Comment: What is **K** and where is **b** ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent In that case K is the matrix defining the polytope, and b is (0 , ..., 0, 1) with 10x  0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear (cf my comment) but you should use **pycddlib**. I tried and I got something close to your expectation:

```python
import numpy as np
import cdd as pcdd

A = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,1], [1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0]])
K = A - A.transpose()
C = np.vstack( (K, -np.eye(5), [1]*5) )
b = [[0]]*10 + [[1]]
M = np.hstack( (b, -C) )


mat = pcdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
mat.rep_type = pcdd.RepType.INEQUALITY

poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)
ext = poly.get_generators()
print(ext)
```

which gives:

```
 1 1/3 0 1/3 1/3 0
 1 0 0 0 1/2 1/2
 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

A "1" in the first column means the row represents an extreme point.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will try this solution.