# Finding extreme points of a polytype using pycddlib

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to find the set of all extreme points of a polytype defined by A.x <= b where A is a matrix [[1,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]] and b is a vector [1,0,0]. It is obvious that the answer is [1,0],[0,1],[0,0]. I only need this basic example to understand how pycddlib works for more advanced tasks.

The pycddlib documentation and code examples at this website like this one ([Polytope, Python - find extreme points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783706/polytope-python-find-extreme-points/71796142#71796142)) use only one matrix to define the polyhedron. It is clear that this matrix must be constructed from A and b, but I did not manage to guess how after reading carefully through these things.

I am asking the community for help and hope that working through this very simple example will help other people struggling with this problem. Being a novice on this website with zero reputation, I cannot comment on the existing questions on this topic and had to create a new one.

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cdd

M = np.array([[1,-1,-1],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
mat = cdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
poly = cdd.Polyhedron(mat)
ext = poly.get_generators()
print(ext)
```

Here the first column is vector b = [1,0,0], and the next two columns are the matrix -M = [[-1,-1],[1,0],[0,1]]. This is one of the possible ways I tried to construct matrix M from A and b to guess the correct way. It produces the seemingly correct output:

```
H-representation
begin
3 3 rational
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 0 1
end
```

Here the first column of ones appears to indicate that the row that follows is an extreme point. Hence, extreme points are [0,0],[1,0],[0,1] as desired. I do not understand if I am on the right track or if it is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is the answer. It took me the whole day to come up with it. Hope it helps other folks.

```
import numpy as np
import cdd

#Accepts vector b with m coordinates and matrix A with m rows and n columns. Both inputs should be lists. 
# Each element of b should itself be a list. Say, if b is a 3-vector of ones, then write b = [[1],[1],[1]].
#Returns a list of extreme points of a polytype given by {x: A.x <= b}. 
def ext_points_mat_vec(A,b):
    
    #set A to minus A and transorm it to np array, as c
    A = -np.array(A)
    
    #transorm b to np array, as required by pycddlib
    b = np.array(b)
    
    #make them into one matrix, as required by pycddlib.
    #it means that the first column is vector b and the other columns are matrix A. 
    #for example, if M =  [[-1,-1],[1,0],[0,1]] and b = [[1],[0],[0]], then you get 
    #M = np.hstack((b,A)) = [[1,-1,-1],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]] 
    #No special logic why we do it exactly like that. It's just that pycddlib needs this format. 
    
    M = np.hstack((b,A))
    
    
    #M we have so far is an np array. Turn it into a matrix object that pycddlib needs.
    
    mat = cdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
    
    #Make it into a polytype object that pycddlib needs.
    poly = cdd.Polyhedron(mat)
    
    #Ask pycddlib to give you a matrix of extreme points. Ignore the "H-representation", "begin", "end", first row and first column. 
    #For example, if output is 
    
   # H-representation
   # begin
   # 3 3 rational
   # 1 0 0
   # 1 1 0
   # 1 0 1
   # end

    #then you only need 
    # 0 0
    # 1 0
    # 0 1
    
    #where each row is an extreme point
    
    ext = poly.get_generators()
    
    #make it into a list
    
    ext_points = []
    
    for row in ext:
        
        row = list(row)
        row = row[1:]
        ext_points.append(row)
    
    return ext_points
    
    
    


#demonstration
    
A = [[1,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]]
b = np.array([[1],[0],[0]])
ext_points_mat_vec(A,b)
```

Comment: this is the H-representation, no? You want the V-representation.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You actually figured the representations out correctly. What you input is a so-called *H-representation* (which lists inequalities and possibly also equations), `get_generators()` returns the corresponding *V-representation* (which in turn lists vertices and possibly also extreme rays).

The [manual](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/cdd_home/cddlibman2021.pdf) of `cddlib`, the C-library underlying `pycddlib`, defines the two formats in detail.